# there is other way to get properties of cell in JS then event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()?

Tags: javascript

so I have this problem that I want to compare 2 cells of Chess table that I did.
When I click on cell, I'm getting in `console.log` only td, and the comparison I'm using I have the cell itself (I added photo for example)
so there is other way to get the cell properties when click on it then the `event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()`?

[image: We can see that in the left lower there is td when i click on cell, and when i click on the cell with "inspect" im seeing the cell itself]
here in this function im sending cell and try to compare it to `event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()`
the problem is, that in `event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()` i have "td" and not the "cell" like shonw in the right side of the photo, so i want to know if there is other opetion whel im clicking on some cell of grid(chess table) that i can get the cell itself to be compared.

```
  const handler= Click.bind(null, cell);
    table.addEventListener("click", handler);

    function Click(cell, event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td' )
        {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == cell])
            {
                alert("SOMETEXT")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Properties? Do you mean class? `event.target.className`?

Comment: There's a lot of properties on the cell element, other than `.nodeName`. Not sure what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the target element classes with [`<Element>.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and after check if it's a black or white cell according to its class.

[`<DOMTokenList>.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) is one of methods you can use to check if the element has a specific class in a mordern way, thanks to [@CerebralFart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3315779/cerebralfart) and [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi).

```js
document.onclick = e => {
  const cell = e.target.classList.contains('blackcell')
    ? 'black'
    : 'white';
  console.log(cell);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell blackcell">B</td>
    <td class="cell whitecell">W</td>
    <td class="cell whitecell">W</td>
    <td class="cell blackcell">B</td>
    <td class="cell blackcell">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For a small performance optimization, you could replace `className.split().includes('blackcell')` with `className.indexOf('blackcell') > -1`.

Comment: @CerebralFart Or just write modern code and use `.classList.contains('blackcell')`. And no, `indexOf` is not a performance optimisation, it's just wrong - it would also find elements with the class `white-or-blackcell`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the clarification, sorry for sending the answer a little early, I didn't think I could post since the question was flagged.